# Jquery detect scroll once

Tags: jquery, scroll, detect

Have read that it is possible to detect a scroll with this line:

```
$('window').one('scroll', function() {  } );
```

If have this inline code:

```
var TimeVariable=setInterval(function(){ DoJQueryStuff() },300);

function DoJQueryStuff()
 {
 if(typeof jQuery == "undefined") return;
 window.clearInterval(TimeVariable);
 $('body').one('mousemove', function() { alert('mouse'); } );
 $('window').one('scroll', function() { alert('scroll'); } );
 }
```

DoJQueryStuff is called every 300 ms until JQuery is loaded.
If I move the mouse anywhere on the screen, I got the "mouse" alert.
If I scroll down I do NOT get the "scroll" alert.
i.e. it's not firing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

David

Comment: Rather than checking every 300ms until jQuery loads, would it be possible to add the function into the `ready` function?  `$(document).ready(function() { do stuff });`

Comment: Kyle, $(document) without Jquery loaded would cause an error.  jquery is loading after the pages loaded (this is now what google suggests we do). An example of your idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first please use jquery `ready` http://api.jquery.com/ready/ method. i dont want to say your implementation is wrong but is slower than the jquery ready method.

your scroll function don't get executed basically because you are binding it to the wrong object.
when you refer to the `window` object with jquery don't wrap it in apostrophs.

if you do so, jquery will intern call the `document.getElementsByTagName` and can't find the tagname `window` because `window` is not an child of the `window.document` node. so your scroll detect function never gets fired because jquery can't bind a `eventListener` to your submited element tagname.

simply bind it to `window` without apostrophs. this forces jquery to bind the scroll event directly to the `window` DOM object where your function is correctly fired on scroll.

Example:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(this).one('mousemove', function() { 
        // mouse move
    }).one('scroll', function(){
        // scroll 
    });
});
```

Comment: Google tells us to load jquery after the page has loaded. That's what I'm doing. Then I'm setting a timer to check that jquery has indeed been loaded. I am detecting the mouse move or scroll to load an external js file.  Why does my scroll detect have to be in the ready function?

Comment: i updated my explanation - hope it becomes now more comprehensible

Comment: You can use an onload function when you load jQuery to run any code that depends on it. If you are using a library, it should have a way to add an onload function. If you are not, you can use `<script onload="...">`