# jQuery .one(), how to use it in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a function who's triggering events when we scroll down the page but I need it to trigger the events only once and I can't figure out how to use .one() in my case. Could you give me a hand please ?

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.sized').offset().top + $('.sized').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) 
    {
        $(".rotate").toggleClass("down"),

        jQuery('.skill-bar').each(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).find('.skill-fill').animate(
            {
                width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
            }, 4000);
        });    
    }
});
```

The main problem is that `$(".rotate").toggleClass("down")` triggers each time I reach the anchor and I want it to trigger only once.

The other function just set some divs to a certain width so it dont really matter since they dont go back to their original width:

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rather than use `toggleClass`, check `hasClass` and - if it does not have the class - use `addClass` and the `.each` call.

Comment: Can this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362688/jquery-detect-scroll-once

Comment: `addClass` worked for the rotate function thanks. But for the other part, it might slow down my website because it tries to set the width everytime I reach the point so if you have any idea it would be cool too :p